# Imported data from txt file in Excel using VBA, need partial extraction from header

Tags: excel, vba, import, txt

I am using following vba code to import data from multiple txt files(Delimited by Pipe '|' character) in 1 excel sheet:

```
Sub LoopFiles()

'Variable Declaration
Dim sFilePath As String
Dim sFileName As String

'Specify File Path
sFilePath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path

'Check for back slash
If Right(sFilePath, 1) <> "\" Then
    sFilePath = sFilePath & "\"
End If
    
sFileName = Dir(sFilePath & "*.txt")


Do While Len(sFileName) > 0
    If Right(sFileName, 3) = UCase("txt") Then
        'Display file name in immediate window
        'Debug.Print sFileName
        rNum = LastRowColumn(Application.ActiveSheet)
        Call ImportPipeDelimited(sFilePath, sFileName, rNum + 1)
    End If
    'Set the fileName to the next available file
    sFileName = Dir
Loop

End Sub

Sub ImportPipeDelimited(filePath As String, fileName As String, rowNum)
  With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "TEXT;" & filePath & fileName, Destination:=Range("A" & rowNum))
    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
    .TextFileOtherDelimiter = "|"
    .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 9, 9, 1, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9)
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
  End With

 Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Application.ActiveSheet


 Dim qrytblQueryTable As QueryTable
    For Each qrytblQueryTable In ws.QueryTables
        qrytblQueryTable.Delete
    Next qrytblQueryTable
 End Sub
```

The above code is doing what it is suppose to do, it import all the relevant data from txt files in a folder.

The issue: in every txt file there are headers, which consist of a Username, Company Name and Department as below:

GLD740---------------------------------ABC PVT LIMITED----------------------------------Quality Control

*dashes above is actually not part of txt file data, I've placed these to represent spaces actually, which for some reason the editor doesn't allow.*

the above header is import with every txt files all in one excel cell(which is expected because it is not delimited with any known character pattern), are there any solution to just extract department name(in the right side) using vba code? Please note that department names have varying length, like Production Department, Finance, Admin etc

Any help/suggestions/solutions are much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think the right function is able to do that. In combination with InStrRev you should get what you want.

```
Sub ReadTextFileExample()
    Dim sFileName As String: sFileName= 'directory where the file is
    Dim strTextLine As String
    Dim iFile As Integer: iFile = FreeFile
    Open sFileName For Input As #iFile
    Line Input #1, strTextLine
    company_name= Right(strTextLine, Len(strTextLine) - InStrRev(strTextLine," 
",, vbTextCompare))
    Close #iFile
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, how do I add supported code to let this function know it is on line 1?

Comment: Ok i am using this code to add logic you have given:

Public Function GetHeader2(mFile) As String
Dim FilePath As String
Dim strFirstLine As String

FilePath = mFile
Open FilePath For Input As #1
Line Input #1, strFirstLine

'GetHeader2 = Right(strFirstLine, Len(strFirstLine) - InStrRev(strFirstLine, " ", , vbTextCompare))
GetHeader2 = strFirstLine
Close #1
End Function

But it doesn't return any thing, however, if i return only strFirstLine, it gives complete header

Comment: no it is giving error on line firstline=ReadLine(sFileName, 1), saying object not define

Comment: yes tried that too, it's says " Sub or Function not Defined" highlighting "ReadLine"

Comment: This one i have tested now, and it reads just the first line and splits it, so that you should only get the companies name.